# Multiple layouts and multiple views Android Studio

Tags: android, view

I am trying to build an app and I want to add multiple views in my app. I am struggling to find a way to handle the views properly. If you do it within one class (MainActivity) you need to do some hiding, which I think is not that neet and can be done in a more solid way, but I do not know how.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
    editTextMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgtosend);
    buttonCalibrate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calibrate);
    buttonMove0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Move0);
    buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    buttonDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
    buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    textViewState = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.state);
    textViewRx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.received);


    buttonDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
    buttonSend.setEnabled(false);

    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);
    buttonDisconnect.setOnClickListener(buttonDisConnectOnClickListener);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
    buttonMove0.setOnClickListener(buttonMove0OnClickListener);
    buttonCalibrate.setOnClickListener(buttonCalibrateOnClickListener);
```

For example this is my java code, some of these buttons are not from activity_main.xml but from another xml file. The app just returns a NULL pointer with those buttons, which is logical.

I have seen many ways but I cannot decide which one is the proper one.
What is the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [butterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to help you in this
and you can simply do this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
@BindView(R.id.sample_text) TextView textView;
@BindView(R.id.sample_button) Button button;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ButterKnife.bind(this);
textView.setText("You can change this view accordingly");

@OnClick(R.id.click_button) 
void buttonClick() {  
//..you don't even need the line @InjectView(R.id.click_button) if this 
button isn't being used else where
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your want to show another layout in your activity layout you need to `include` that layout

Including `another_layout.xml` in `activity_main.xml` layout

```
...
<include
    android:id="@+id/included_layout"
    layout="@layout/another_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="bottom"/>
....
```

this code will set the layout of the bottom of main layout.

You can hide this layout as you wish

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.included_layout);
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: I indeed tried this, but than the layouts show on top of each other, and you need to do hiding, which I think is not neet, thanks anyway!

Comment: you have to handle that... where to show.... I edit the answer.. that code will show the view bottom of the main view and your can hide the view as you want...